# Ensure Mongoose Save Completes Before Callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redirect, mongoose, synchronous

I'm running into issues while writing my first node app where my callback gets called before the write to the database is actually finished.

The scenario is that when an authenticated user goes to the url site.com/model, the database is queried to see if there is a model that belongs to the user. If there is, it is displayed to the user. If there isn't the user is redirected to site.com/model/create which has a form that can be submitted. When that form is submitted, the model is saved to the database and the user is redirected to site.com/model where they are displayed the newly created object. Issue is, in the code below, the redirect in the callback of the save happens before the write is completed. Which means when the user is redirected to site.com/model after submitting the new model, the new model is not written yet which means they are redirected again back to site.com/model/create, though if I wait and refresh on the page, the model was created. Any idea how to ensure that the write completes before redirecting? Sorry if my question isn't clear, I'd be happy to answer questions to clear it up.

```
router.get('/model', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Model.findOne({'owner': req.user.username}, function(err, card) {
        if(err) {

        }

        if(model) {
            res.render('model', {
                user : req.user,
                model : model
            });
        } 
        else {
            res.redirect('/model/create');
        }
    });
});
router.get('/model/create', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Model.findOne({'owner': req.user.username}, function(err, card) {
        if(err) {

        }

        if(model) {
            res.redirect('/model');
        } 
        else {  
            res.render('model/create', {
                user : req.user
            });
        }
    });
});

router.post('/model/create', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    req.body.model.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }

        res.redirect('/model');
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to use create when try to save the data or first create instance of the data being saved as "new MODEL_NAME " & then use save for saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

`req.body.model` is most likely the form data (converted to JSON) sent by client. I'm not sure how it even has a `.save` method that you're calling in your code.

Usually you're supposed to create a new model instance with this data and save that:

```
new Model(req.body.model).save(...)
```

Comment: You're totally right. This code is stripped of my conversion logic since I didn't see it as relevant and I made a mistake in taking out too much of it. Question still pretty much stands though of how to wait until the save of the proper object does go through

Comment: To answer the question in your title, `.save` method does actually complete the saving process (persisting data into database) before calling the callback function. So if you're really doing everything right it should work out as you expected.